# IE remove parameters from URL

Tags: internet-explorer, oauth-2.0

I tried to get access token after Microsoft authentication. I type in URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={my-client-id}
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=https://localhost/
&scope=openid+{my-API}
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce={my-once}
```

After running this URL in IE11 I got a right response in URL `https://localhost/#access_token=ey...`, but after it immediately page is refreshed and I got `https://localhost/`

[image]

Comment: Whether this behavior only occurred in IE browser, try to use another browser to test it. 
It seems that you are using the build-in method to verify the user, after validate success, it will redirect to the destination page. If you want to get the access token, you could send a POST request to the /token endpoint programmatically. Also, you could try to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send the request, then check the response.

Comment: Of course, I use other browsers. This problem only happens in IE. In postman is ok. POST is not working. Let check ms official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a build in action, as it said in [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) "After signing in, your browser should be redirected to https://localhost/myapp/ with a code in the address bar."  If you want to get the access token, you could execute the request  in Postman.